# How to get SaveDialogBox combobox values

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I want to set extension of file if user did not do this and concatenate the file name and extension-combobox-string.Is there some easy way to do so, or i need some "hooks"?

```
    OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
    TCHAR szFile[260];       // buffer for file name                      
    HANDLE hFile;              // file handle

    // Initialize OPENFILENAME
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    // Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
    // use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = 0;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = _T("Текстові файли(*.txt)\0*.txt\0Word(*.doc)\0*.doc\0");
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER;   

    if(GetSaveFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
    {
        hFile = CreateFile( szFile,
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
            CREATE_NEW,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            (HANDLE)NULL);

        int editLen = Edit_GetTextLength(edit);
        TCHAR* buffer = new TCHAR[editLen+1];
        DWORD wroteLen = 0;

        Edit_GetText(edit,buffer,editLen+1);
        //Set extension if need

        ///////////////////////
        if(!WriteFile(hFile,buffer,editLen*sizeof(TCHAR),&wroteLen,NULL))
            MessageBox(hwnd,_T("File wasn`t saved.."),_T("Error"),MB_ICONERROR);

        CloseHandle(hFile);
        delete[]buffer;
```

Thank you for response! ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ofn.nFilterIndex` is set to the 1-based index of the file extension combobox selection.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the `lpstrDefExt` member:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Type: LPCTSTR
>
> The default extension.
>
> GetOpenFileName and
> GetSaveFileName append this extension to the file name if the user
> fails to type an extension. This string can be any length, but only
> the first three characters are appended. The string should not contain
> a period (.). If this member is NULL and the user fails to type an
> extension, no extension is appended.

Comment: Yes thanks, but if comboBox string is not DefExt i do not want to set Default Extension but the comboBox extension

Comment: I believe that's what this does. Try it and let us know.